# Can you launch the camera app for both photo and video recording?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on an application. I have a button that says "Take Photo or Video", and when the user presses it, I'd like the default camera on either iOS or Android to open. After which, the user would be able to take a single photo or take a single video before confirming they'd like to send it.

I've been looking and testing through packages like react-native-image-picker and react-native-image-crop-picker but they all seem to have a similar problem. I can choose to open the camera so that it will only take a photo, or open the camera to only take a video. Upon closer inspection of the documentation, these packages do not support both. Does anyone know of any packages/methods that will allow the user to choose between the two. E.G when I open the camera on my Samsung phone, I can tap the capture button to take a photo, or I can hold it down to record a video. I would like that functionality for the user if possible so that I do not need separate "take a photo" and "take a video" buttons in my application.